# Check if coordinate lies inside a polygon c#

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, math

I am using the code to check if a coordinate lies inside a polygon or not, But whenever I test a coordinate that is close to the boundary for e.g 300 meters sometimes it returns true, sometimes false.

Below is the function I am using

```
  public static bool IsPointInPolygon2(SentinelLocation[] polygon,SentinelLocation p)
    {
        double minX = polygon[0].Longitude;
        double maxX = polygon[0].Longitude;
        double minY = polygon[0].Latitude;
        double maxY = polygon[0].Latitude;
        for (int i = 1; i < polygon.Length; i++)
        {
            SentinelLocation q = polygon[i];
            minX = Math.Min(q.Longitude, minX);
            maxX = Math.Max(q.Longitude, maxX);
            minY = Math.Min(q.Latitude, minY);
            maxY = Math.Max(q.Latitude, maxY);
        }

        if (p.Longitude < minX || p.Longitude > maxX || p.Latitude < minY || p.Latitude > maxY)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // https://wrf.ecse.rpi.edu/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html
        bool inside = false;
        for (int i = 0, j = polygon.Length - 1; i < polygon.Length; j = i++)
        {
            if ((polygon[i].Latitude > p.Latitude) != (polygon[j].Latitude > p.Latitude) &&
                 p.Longitude < (polygon[j].Longitude - polygon[i].Longitude) * (p.Latitude - polygon[i].Latitude) / (polygon[j].Latitude - polygon[i].Latitude) + polygon[i].Longitude)
            {
                inside = !inside;
            }
        }

        return inside;
    }
```

This is the test data i am passing

```
 public bool IsInsidePolyGon(double latitude,double longitude)
    {
        var location = new SentinelLocation
        {
            Latitude = latitude,
            Longitude = longitude,
        };
        var polygon = new List<SentinelLocation>();
        polygon.Add(new SentinelLocation
        {
            Latitude = 31.82703,
            Longitude = 63.23671
        });
        polygon.Add(new SentinelLocation
        {
            Latitude = 34.54806,
            Longitude = 61.91835
        });

        polygon.Add(new SentinelLocation
        {
            Latitude = 35.37638,
            Longitude = 67.32363
        });
        polygon.Add(new SentinelLocation
        {
            Latitude = 32.71876,
            Longitude = 67.19179
        });
      

        var toReturn = PolyUtil.IsPointInPolygon2(polygon.ToArray(),location);
        return toReturn;
    }
```

Test case on which this fails is Latitude:34.96946 and Longitude 64.66381

My polygon looks like this

[image]

Can anyone guide me what's going wrong here?

Comment: Why is `minX` and `maxX` equal? Why is `minY` and `maxY` equal?

Comment: @Charlieface That is to initialize the variable, Took this piece of code from here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-2d-point-is-within-a-polygon). Check the C# version.

If you notice min, max are correctly assigned values in the for loop.

Comment: My guess would be that the formula your using is for determining points inside of a flat polygon and doesn't take the curvature of the earth into account.

Comment: @juharr how can I fix it? I want a formula that tells me if the coordinate is inside a polygon or not, Regardless of the polygon shape...